# No services listed when SQL Server Express 2008 R2 Installed on local computer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I cannot get my local computer to run SQL Server. I looked in the SQL Server configuration manager and noticed that there are no SQL Server Services listed. That can't be right. I also noticed that There are two Managers listed in the SysWOW64 folder (I'm running Win7): SQLServerManager10.msc and SQLServerManager.msc. Neither show any services at all. When trying to connect via SSMSE, I get the standard:

```
    A network related or instance specific error occurred while establishing a 
connection to SQL server...
```

I haven't installed a prior version, but did try to uninstall and reinstall using the Web platform installer from Microsoft. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is SQL Server listed in services? (Start->Run->Services.msc)
If so, is it running?

Comment: No, it's not listed there at all.

Comment: It sounds like you didn't get everything installed. Launch the install file and chose the option "New installation or add features to an existing installation". From there you should be able to make sure the database engine service gets installed.

Comment: That was it. Somewhere in there, the correct version or something got uninstalled or never installed. I redownloaded just the SQL Server 2008 R2 Express and installed it. Now it works fine. Sometimes the MS stuff is confusing. When it works, it's great. When it doesn't...hours of head banging. At least for me. Thanks.

Comment: on windows 8 i just installed SQL Server 2008 R2 standard edition. i can connect it via management studio using . or (local) but it is not listed. how can i resolve this?

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem and as Brian said, I was missing SQL Server Express. So I download [SQL Server 2008 R2 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3743&hash=tzpse2Hf2ugsYSBt8XEteDEGlAFO/4OCgr20w0BFq3JMZiaLd9T5n%2bBGQwbOmpZi%2b43Dw4NKM0jlkEDRRMhw1g==) and I installed it. now everything works fine.

Note that I thought I already installed it when I installed [SQL Management Studio R2](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22985&hash=R77gu91vBua9isLwTSGAupJUJEl8vmHGBkUr1g6xvIAcfvSAfjTQTvfEDOypiDyyyPZwAXtw5u/F6/4bn3FIcQ==). Now, be aware that when installing SQL Management Studio R2, you are not installing SQL Server and you won't get any SQL Server Services in your Sql Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Services. You also need to download and install SQL Server Express.

Answer (score 0):

That is an instance error, meaning you cannot connect to the instance. Most likely there is no instance installed on this machine. Meaning your not connecting correctly to the instance. Connect to the database engine again and check the server name and make sure your connecting to the correct server name or the local host, depending if this is a local machine or if this is on a server. Go back through setup and see if there are any features that didn't get installed. Try that and see if it works. If not then reinstall SQL Server and make sure all folders are removed and nothing is left behind before you reinstall.